# Can't mount ext4-formatted USB

Tags: usb, linux-mint, ext4, exfat

I have recently bought a USB, which is initially formatted using exFAT. Then I tried wiping it off and format it with ext4. But then, Linux Mint 20 doesn't seem to be able to mount it. When I checked the "disks" utility, the USB appeared, but it just displayed the loading loop. I tried to cancel the mount job, no luck either. Then I tried a live Linux Mint 19, also can't open the USB, so this is clearly not a problem with my existing computer.

Then I booted up my Windows copy (dual boot with Mint 20), plugged the USB in, formatted it to exFAT, and Windows can then open it. Then I boot up Mint 20 and live Mint 19 and both can open it. So my question is, do USB manufacturers restrict the type of filesystems a USB can have? I have never heard of this phenomenon, and can you give me some source to read more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have dug into this a whole lot for the past few days and I think I know what's wrong. I tried to create an ext4 partition, didn't work. I then tried to fix it using fsck, also no dice. Then I tried to create an ext4 partition with less size (60GB), and then it works, with no corruption. It turns out that I just got scammed by the manufacturer.

Comment: Hi, I have similar issue. I don't understand your solution. What was the initial size of your pendrive? Is it about resizing partition, so it will not take the entire usb, or is it about file system?

Comment: @s-kaczmarek So the advertised volume is 1TB, but turns out in reality it only has 64GB of space. So when I do all shenanigans with the whole 1TB, nothing works well, but if I do everything with 60GB only, leaving 4GB for some overhead, everything works well. What I did was just wipe the drive clean, then create a new 60GB partition, then format it with a specific filesystem as usual. I didn't really resize anything. If you need more details, I can PM you.

Comment: for me, creating new partition with the size of entire usb drive with ntfs file system works fine. It seems like pen drives don't really like other file systems.

Comment: Oh so if you are using Windows, then it can only read NTFS partitions, which may explain why pen drives don't like other partitions. Historically, pen drives like FAT, FAT32 and exFAT only.